# Android I get error closing itext pdf: Trailer not found

Tags: java, android, itext

Sometimes i have this problem when signing and closing the pdf.
I have no problem trying the same pdf on different devices.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(SRC);
   PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(DEST_PREP);
   com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader, 
   pdfWriter);
   pdfAttachments(pdfDoc);
   pdfReader.close();
   pdfWriter.close();
}

void pdfAttachments(com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument pdfDoc){
   byte[] SMSOTP_FileContentBytes = (AppEngine.SMSOTP_Data).getBytes();
   PdfFileSpec SMSOTP_spec = PdfFileSpec.createEmbeddedFileSpec(pdfDoc, SMSOTP_FileContentBytes, SMSOTP_FileDescription, SMSOTP_FileName, null, null, null);
   pdfDoc.addFileAttachment("embedded_file_SMSOTP", SMSOTP_spec);
   pdfDoc.close();
}
```

**Firebase Crashlytics;**

```
Non-fatal Exception: com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException
Trailer not found.
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.rebuildXref (PdfReader.java:1138)
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf (PdfReader.java:592)
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open (PdfDocument.java:1830)
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init> (PdfDocument.java:323)
com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.initDocument (PdfSigner.java:306)
com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.<init> (PdfSigner.java:288)
com.itextpdf.signatures.PdfSigner.<init> (PdfSigner.java:271)
SignPdfActivity$SignFileTask.doInBackground (SignPdfActivity.java:1895)
SignPdfActivity$SignFileTask.doInBackground (SignPdfActivity.java:1780)
android.os.AsyncTask$3.call (AsyncTask.java:394)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: As you can see in the stack trace, the problem occurs while trying to read the original pdf. If that only happens occasionally, it might be a timing issue. It's the file probably not yet there? Or was it temporary and has already been deleted?